# Customize camera overlay in applozic

Tags: ios, swift, chat, applozic

I am using **applozic chat sdk for ios** and  sending images , video successfully . My requirement is to change camera overlay. When I try to add overlay on camera it crashes.

```
 let camaraObj : ALImagePickerController = ALImagePickerController()

 let overlay =UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()     
 camaraObj.cameraOverlayView = overlay
```

> Crash log: **libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.**

Any help ?

Comment: Please add crash log for more detail.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
Nothing prints on console except this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are not setting the sourceType. **ALImagePickerController** is used for sending pictures from photos only. You need to explicitly set source type if you want to use it for camera.

i.e.    `self.mImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`

We just tried the same and got below exception:

**2017-01-30 14:30:30.954540 applozicdemo[3106:1925853] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type must be UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera' First throw call stack:
(0x1819de1c0 0x18041855c 0x187a945cc 0x187d23294 0x1003f9dcc 0x10016525c 0x10016521c 0x10016a284 0x18198bf2c 0x181989b18 0x1818b8048 0x18333e198 0x1878a42fc 0x18789f034 0x1000517b8 0x18089c5b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

Comment: Hi adarsh , we tried this but overlay is not showing when we open camera in chat attachment. But yes it ignore crash. We are still trying to add overlay on camera.

Comment: Can you please try with frame from picker-view itself?

Comment: Can you please suggest code and where to add this code. As we are adding this in AppDelegate when application launching.

Comment: You can use something like :

     let camaraObj : ALImagePickerController = ALImagePickerController()
     let overlay = UIView(frame: camaraObj.view.frame)
     camaraObj.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
      overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
      camaraObj.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

       self.present(camaraObj, animated:true, completion: nil)

Comment: Got the updatable code from [here](https://www.applozic.com/blog/add-applozic-chat-framework-ios/) . Now i can customize as per my requirements.